# Retrieving value of document references from firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I'm attempting to retrieve an object from firestore (a question object) which has among other things a few fields of type DocumentReference (Example: Topic, referring to a document in the topics collection). The goal here is to retrieve all question objects from the question collection, display all their properties in a table and the DocumentReferences should be resolved and the "name" property on the retrieved objects should be displayed. Getting all the questions were easy to do, but for some reason what I'm doing to resolve the DocumentReferences is causing the whole app to freeze

#### themes.service.ts

```
  getThemeNameByRef(ref: DocumentReference): Observable<string> {
     if (ref) {
         return this.db.doc(`themes/${ref.id}`).get()
         .pipe(
           map((action) => {
              return action.data().name;
           }), shareReplay(1))

      }}
```

#### Question-explorer.component.html

```
  <div *ngFor="let question of questions">
    {{question.difficulty}}
    {{themeService.getThemeNameByRef(question.theme) | async}}
  </div>
```

I have removed its inclusion in a table and used something simpler to eliminate that being the cause of the issue. I've tried plenty of different ways to retrieve the reference like calling get() directly on the DocumentReference object, creating an AngularFirestoreDocument object and I seem to be getting either the same freezing issue or the page would load but the template would resolve the value to null so nothing would be displayed.

Looking at Chrome dev tools, only one HTTP request is going out but the observable is getting called an infinite amount of times which is what is causing the side effect of it freezing. Why that's happening though is what I can't figure out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part way to a solution:

I'm not sure what's happening for you, I would expect one HTTP call per question in the questions array.

Regardless, composing data directly in an HTML template is probably a poor choice in the long term. It's hard to extend and may cause the view to display strangely if results from your service call come back out of order or at differing intervals.

In your component somewhere I would write something like:
(Note that I'm not sure how `questions` is defined, so I can't advise on where/how `viewQuestions$` should be declared/defined, I leave that up to you)

```js
viewQuestions$ = forkJoin(
  this.questions.map(question => 
    themeService.getThemeNameByRef(question.theme).pipe(
      map(theme => ({...question, theme}))
    )
  )
);
```

Then in your HTML template

```html
<div *ngFor="let question of viewQuestions$ | async">
  {{question.difficulty}}
  {{question.theme}}
</div>
```

This has the benefit of a much simpler template. All the service calls are being done before they're displayed, so there's no strange flickering on the user's screen.

You can probably also debug this a bit more easily as well. You can use RxJS operators to log results, catch errors, retry service calls, ect.

---

So for example, if you want to log the questions before they are displayed, you can do something like this:

```js
viewQuestions$ = forkJoin(
  this.questions.map(question => 
    themeService.getThemeNameByRef(question.theme).pipe(
      map(theme => ({...quesiton, theme}))
    )
  )
).pipe(
  tap(console.log)
);
```

#### Abstracting further to build `viewQuestions$`

This is the same thing as above but for any number of properties. The nice thing about `forkjoin` is that it accepts a dictionary (JS Object) and will return an object of the same shape with the properties resolved to the final values of the given observables. Very handy!

You can see that used here:

```js
viewQuestions$ = this.getQuestionsService(args).pipe(
  switchMap(questions => forkJoin(
    questions.map(question => 
      forkJoin({
        theme: this.themeService.getThemeNameByRef(question.theme),
        property2: this.service.getThingy2(question.something2),
        property3: this.service.getThingy3(question.something3)
      }).pipe(
        map(properties => ({...question, ...properties}))
      )
    )
  ))
);
```

In your template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let question of viewQuestions$ | async">
  {{question.difficulty}}
  {{question.theme}}
  {{question.property2}}
  {{question.property3}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is truly beautiful, my ideal solution involved having everything resolved in one go and that's what you did here. This will serve as a great starting point to build my table as it's resolving the documents correctly. Thank you for the help and please keep doing your thing!

Comment: How many DocumentReference are on a question?

Comment: Currently 5, I see what you did there that is pretty clean. I'll implement it tonight. Thank you!!